# Select data from table based on mulitple column combination

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select data from a table based on multiple combinations of `height` and `width` columns. However, the query I'm using isn't working.

```
$sql_wallpaper = "
    SELECT *
    FROM wallpaper
    WHERE categoryid = $catid
    WHERE height = 1080
    OR width = 2560
    OR width = 1366
    OR height = 720
    OR width = 2560
    AND height = 1600
    OR width = 1680
    AND height = 1050
    OR width = 1920
    AND height = 1200
    OR width = 1280
    AND height = 800
    OR width = 1440
    AND height = 900
    ORDER BY wallpaperid DESC
    LIMIT $from,$max_results
";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Two WHERE clauses in the statement, and then a combination of ANDs and ORs (without any braces) that looks like you don't really understand boolean logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your SQL is wrong:

```
select * from wallpaper
  where categoryid = $catid
  where height = 1080 OR width = 2560  OR width = 1366
     OR height = 720 OR width = 2560 AND height = 1600
     OR width = 1680 AND height = 1050 OR width = 1920
    AND height = 1200 OR width = 1280 AND height = 800
     OR width = 1440 AND height = 900
  order by wallpaperid desc
  limit $from,$max_results
```

You have two `WHERE`s in there. You should be using `AND` in place of the second, maybe wrap everything into parens.

But also try using `print mysql_error()` in your scripts. Especially for debugging when something doesn't work. MySQL will tell you what's wrong with your queries most of the time.

---

Very well. Your rewritten query:

```
select * from wallpaper
  where categoryid = $catid
    AND (
        height = 1080 OR width = 2560  OR width = 1366
     OR height = 720 OR width = 2560 AND height = 1600
     OR width = 1680 AND height = 1050 OR width = 1920
    AND height = 1200 OR width = 1280 AND height = 800
     OR width = 1440 AND height = 900
        )
  order by wallpaperid desc
  limit $from,$max_results
```

But what you probably should be using for simplicity is:

```
SELECT * FROM wallpaper
  WHERE categoryid = $catid
    AND width IN (1440, 2560, 1366, 1680, 1920, 1280)
    AND height IN (1200, 800, 900, 1080, 720, 1600, 1050)
  ORDER BY wallpaperid DESC
  LIMIT $from,$max_results
```

Comment: PLease place a Fix Code thats its work fine for me..  if Second WHERE i didnt use then what i USE  or If i use braces  then where i use it in this code

Comment: `You should be using AND in place of the second WHERE`. Add a parenthesis around the other conditions thereafter and until before the ORDER BY.

Comment: It is not a great idea to edit the body of answers given to your question. It is better to edit your question; I have rolledback the edit.

Comment: NOT WORK  .. PLease Fix This CODE .. thats whats in your mine

Comment: Good suggestion to use `IN`, but the second solution doesn't do exactly the same as the first (which is probably what the OP intended to do): I can now choose a resolution of 2560 x 720, which I think is invalid. Nice write-up, though.

Comment: @Marcel: True. I already considered posting a `(width, height) IN ( (800,600), (1600,1200), ...)` array map instead (which I just discovered is possible). But it's probably overkill for OPs case, and I couldn't quite figure out which sizes he wanted to match in what combination.

Comment: THanks it Work Great I Love it